# Most efficient way to store big hexadecimal number (md5) in java object

Tags: java, groovy, md5

What will be the most efficient way (optimal for performance and storage space) to store the `MD5` sum of file in a java (or groovy) object considering the following use-cases:

1. I need to compare with thousands of other md5 sums.
2. I may need to store this in HSQLDB, so that records can be pulled/`group by` based on md5
3. May be stored in `Map`'s as keys

I am trying to avoid storing it as `String` as String comparisons will be more costly and take more space. Will `BigInteger(string,radix)` be more efficient? Also, what datatype should be selected if persisting in database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a class that wraps a `byte[]` and provides no mutation.  If you want to use it as a key in a map, then it needs to either be comparable, or have a hash code.  With a `byte[]` you'll have an easier time computing a simple hashcode from the first 32 bits.

Comment: thanks you you answer. With groovy `new BigInteger(1,digest).toString(16).padLeft(32,'0')` can take care of generating the hash from `byte[]` but not sure if that's 'efficient'. If I had to choose between BigInt and String, what would you suggest? I asking this because this is just a groovy script and creating a wrapper may be overkill (if it doesnot have huge performance benefit).

Comment: @kunal, if forced to choose between bigint and string, I would choose BigInteger.  A string is just not space efficient when you store a series of hex digits as a string naively.  You could pack bits into UTF-16 code-units, but there's no compelling reason to go to the trouble.  The most you save for all that work is 16b over a BigInteger.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. As @erickson mentioned, what about storing it as long?

Comment: @kunal, if it fits in 16B, then sure.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison speed in Java, storing it as two `long` values will likely be fastest. For persistence, storage as a byte array makes the most sense, if your database and persistence tools support it. Otherwise, storage as hexadecimal or Base-64–encoded text is fairly common and will inter-operate well with other applications that access the same database.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform a lot of comparisons, you could store the MD5 value as 2 `long` integers, that way you only need to perform at most 4 logical operations to check against another MD5 value.

Basically, provide a class that will accept an input, a raw digest data as `byte[]` and use

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(digestData);
long[] bits = new long[] {
    bb.getLong(),
    bb.getLong()
};
```

Compare with another `long[]` MD5 array with

```
boolean eq = ((bits[0]^otherBits[0]) | (bits[1]^otherBits[1])) == 0);
```

Reconstruct the MD5 with

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
bb.putLong(bits[0]);
bb.putLong(bits[1]);

byte[] digestData = new byte[16];
bb.get(digestData);
```

**Note** : I am not suggesting to convert the `byte[]` into `long[]` for every comparisons, this is simply how to store the digest *for* comparisons. The last reconstruction snippet is optional, you should keep the data as `byte[]` and compare the `long[]` arrays only. In the database, store the data as a 32 bytes hexadecimal value.

Comment: -1 : long is always 64 bits, regardless of the JVM. And there's no need for all these transformations. Long.SIZE is a constant. Checking it has no point. Just store it as a byte array and use java.util.Arrays.equals(byte[], byte[]).

Comment: @JB Nizel, the question asked for performance, and checking Arrays.equals(byte[], byte[]) is less efficient than performing the check that I'm suggesting. The API exists for convenience, and while I usually suggest the Java API in most cases, this is not the case here.

Comment: public static boolean isEqual(byte[] digesta,
                              byte[] digestb) in MessageDigest [see here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#isEqual%28byte[],%20byte[]%29) can compare two digest (byte[]) too. Again, i am not sure about the performance.

Comment: @kunal, it will still be slower than comparing two `long` values. The method `isEqual` does not take into account the digested method, therefore it simply performs a similar operation as `Arrays.equals`.